# SQL in PHP seems to not work

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write some Data in my MySQL database but it seems to not work.
All the variables are filled, tested it by echoing them. Now I want to insert them into my sip table but it just doesnt do it.

Where did I go wrong on this?

```
echo $a_dw.$a_name.$a_an.$a_pw."<br>";
$sql = "INSERT INTO sip VALUES ('".$a_dw."','".$a_name."', '".$a_an."', '".$a_pw."')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No I didnt. It just displayed the echos.

Comment: can we see your connection part? full code for your connection ?

Comment: holy moly. i think i just failed on another level. I deleted my connection part yesterday and didnt add it again. Thanks a lot. problem solved :s

Comment: but try to migrate from `mysql` into `mysqli` or `PDO` !

Comment: whats the difference between these? and why should i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

You forgot the column names.

Comment: Tried with and without column names, doesnt work either.

Edit: Its part of the Solution. These were missing yes, but i didnt set up the database connection.

Comment: No, you do have to list the column names in insert statement, in this case mysql expects values for all fields to be provided in the order they are in the table.

Comment: okay, but it didnt work? do i have to adress the ID (which is my primary key as auto increment) aswell? cause i didnt do that.

Comment: You could provide null for the id field and not list the column names. The answer is still incorrect, since the question does not say anything about the number of fields in the table, and the answer implies that you have to list the field names every time, which is not correct. Moreover, this alone would not have solved your problem either. I would remove this question completely.